# CSS to GLTF objects in THREE.js

Tags: css, three.js, aframe

Is it possible to give CSS to an GLTF model in THREE.js, like let say transparency?
I mean, not in javascript but with CSS style?
Something like

```
<style>
.trans {
 opacity: 0.5;
}
</style>
```

and than

```
<a-asset-item class="trans">
</a-asset-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS cannot be natively applied to WebGL, regardless of the engine or model format.

Since I see you're using A-Frame, you may want to check out [aframe-mss](https://github.com/ngokevin/aframe-mss) which adds (using JavaScript, not the browser's CSS implementation) a CSS-like syntax that may work with models loaded into A-Frame.

Related: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/1102